# MAPI Profile creation problems to connect exchange server 2013

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi, exchange-server-2013

I am working on to create MAPI profile programatically to connect Exchange Server 2013. But in exchange server 2013 due to some advanced settings [outlook anywhere] i need to add some additional properties as described in the below aricle.

[MSDN Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2013/05/21/how-to-mfcmapi-create-mapi-profile-exchange-2013.aspx)

I can able to retrieve the following important property values through Autodicover.

```
PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER
PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_SERVER
PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER_AUTH_PACKAGE
```

And iam able to create profile by adding the properties. But i faced the following difficulties,

1. Sometimes without adding the additional properties described in the above **msdn** article i able to create the mapi profile and connect exchange server. In such cases, if i add the additional properties then iam unable to connect the exchange server successfully with the profile.

   `i am getting the MAPI error "MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED".`

And in most of the exchange server 2013 environment, if i add the additional properties then only i can able to connect exchange server successfully.

I am confused..! In what circumstance we need to add the additional MAPI properties `[PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER,PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_SERVER,......]`to connect exchange server 2013 in a MAPI profile???

And i am unable to find the exact causes in the exchange server environments.

Iam struggling to find the solution for more than a week.

can anyone please help me on this.

If need any additional information, i am happy to provide.

NOTE: I am able to create MAPI profile to connect exchange server 2010 without any issues.

Comment: The article deals with the standalone (Exchange) version of MAPI? Is that what you are using? Do you specify the credentials or pass the parent window handle to let MAPI display the authentication prompt?

Comment: Dmitry, Sorry for not poining out that. Yes, iam using standalone mapi version 6.5.8309. No i do not specify the credentials in any mapi display prompt. I just open the command prompt under the user who has mailbox in exchange server and have full administrator priviliges. Then i will ran my excutable through that. 

FYI: I have used mfcmapi utility and faced the same issue

Comment: As a test, can you download Redemption and check if RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) works against that mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2013 *requires* those RPC over HTTP properties because it no longer supports RPC over TCP/IP.  For earlier versions of Exchange, they're optional.